# Removing old faucet valve

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

We are replacing a roman tub faucet trim and the spout hole is smaller than that of the original. The previous faucet valve seems to be stuck on the pipe. Is it possible to remove it? Picture of valve below

https://imgur.com/gallery/gTg1wsF

Comment: If the spring clip in the centre moves, then might just need two bigger wrenches.  If it does not move by giving it a decent tap, then it might be holding a lock.

Comment: did you try to remove that ring

Comment: the circular ring in the center seems to be threaded on the pipe. I tried to rotate it counter clockwise to loosen it but the cylindrical piece above it wont budge.